# Azure Event Hub With Net Core Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-eventhub

I am new with Azure event hub.My requirement is that I want to listen from one of the third-party azure event hub(I have only connection-string of third party event hub and my own storage account) that will send updates to me if some specific event is occurred at third-party side after that In my app I need to check in database that how many user has subscribe to that event and need to send them notification in phone(through Firebase SDK).So how can I achieve that behavior in Net Core Web API().

I read that we can use webhook with Azure event hub but did not find any good resource for that if you have any resource please share with me.

I have also read that we can use WebJob but did not find any code resource for that if you have any resource please share with me.

Thanks in advance if you have any help for me.

Comment: Have you considered using Azure functions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging into your project and use it to send notifications to users' phones.

- Implement the logic to query your database for subscribed users based on the received event and send notifications using the Firebase SDK.
- You'll need to install the [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://i.imgur.com/AMGVUcG.png) (FCM) for sending notifications.
  `dotnet add package FirebaseAdmin`
- Configuration your **appsettings.json** file by adding the connection string for the third-party Azure Event Hub.

```
{
  "AzureEventHubConnectionString": "your_connection_string_here",
  "FirebaseConfigFilePath": "firebase_admin_sdk.json"
}
```

- `firebase_admin_sdk.json` you can get this by adding/creating the sample web application in Firebase project navigate to project settings>service account there you can see generate new private key.

[image]

Click on generate then you can see a json file downloaded in your local. Give the file path in the [appsettings.json](https://i.imgur.com/0o0msWY.png)

- Here I Enabled service agent to generate primary key access to my application.

[image]

- Below is the `EventProcessor` class that can listen to events from the Azure Event Hub and process them, including sending notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging when a specific event is received.

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;
using FirebaseAdmin;
using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class EventProcessor
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<EventProcessor> _logger;
    private readonly FirebaseApp _firebaseApp;

    public EventProcessor(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<EventProcessor> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;

        // Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
        _firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(_configuration["FirebaseConfigFilePath"])
        });
    }

    public async Task StartProcessing()
    {
        string eventHubConnectionString = _configuration["AzureEventHubConnectionString"];
        string eventHubName = "traileventhub382";

        await using (var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName, eventHubConnectionString, eventHubName))
        {
            await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Process the incoming event data here
                    string eventData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(partitionEvent.Data.Body.ToArray());
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Received event: {eventData}");

                    // Example: Send a notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging
                    var message = new Message
                    {
                        Notification = new Notification
                        {
                            Title = "Notification Title",
                            Body = "Notification Body"
                        },
                        // Add necessary targeting options here
                    };

                    var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Notification sent: {response}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Error processing event: {ex}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here Iam able to listen the messages that are captured in the EventHub monitoring metrics.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**BackgroundService.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class EventHubBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<EventHubBackgroundService> _logger;

    public EventHubBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<EventHubBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var eventProcessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EventProcessor>();
                await eventProcessor.StartProcessing();
            }

            // Adjust the frequency at which you want to check for new events
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

- Here I created a scope and resolve the `EventProcessor` to call the `StartProcessing()` method at regular intervals. You can adjust the delay as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your code.It really helped me but from where I want to call StartProcessing() because in production environment we can get event anytime so who will be the responsible for calling StartProcessing() method.Thanks for your help

Comment: @HarshJoshi, By creating a background service or worker process you can continuously listens to events from the Azure Event Hub and calls the StartProcessing() method. I had updated my answer please check.

Comment: @SureshChikkam Thanks for refrence what if I want to use azure function with your code ??

Comment: @HarshJoshi, Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to use in Azure functions or else If you need it in detail create another question for your requirement.